# Please help build this motto!

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Please help me build this motto: Learn Latin and learn so much more.

Or suggest a better motto if you have any ideas! This is for Latin courses that are being offered at a school.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is the "so much more" other languages, information about peoples, history, and culture related to Latin, or all of the above?